# New Angular project using the command ng new, error: "npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree"

Tags: angular-cli

I wanted to create a new Angular project using the command `ng new <projectname>` and I got this error:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: project@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^17.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"17.0.9" from @angular/forms@17.0.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!   @angular/forms@"^17.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/akshara/.npm/_logs/2024-01-17T15_07_28_234Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/akshara/.npm/_logs/2024-01-17T15_07_28_234Z-debug-0.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
```

I have updated the Angular CLI and Node.js versions, but to no avail.